# setState() called in constructor: UserDisplay#11a4b(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update the display after I tap on a card.
I use InkWell widget to get the `ontap` method and modified the class to extend the State class. (see bellow)

But i cant get setState to run whatever i do. I always get the same error message:

```
setState() called in constructor: UserDisplay#11a4b(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not
mounted)
```

State file:

```
class groupView extends State<MyApp> {
  final String groupParam;
  groupView({required this.groupParam, Key? key});
  List<userData> _response = [DefaultUser()];
  final _dataservice = DbGet();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Group ${groupParam}"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    UserDisplay().dataCard(_response, uHeight, context),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

other file:

```
class UserDisplay extends groupView {
  UserDisplay({Key? key,}) : super(groupParam: "groupParam", key: key);

  Widget DataCard(String dataText, double uHeight, context) {
    // dataText == null ? dataText = "" : dataText = dataText;
    Color MyColor = Colors.blue;
    Color MyColorText = Colors.white;
    var _dataText;

    if (dataText == "1") {
      MyColor = Colors.blue;
      MyColorText = Colors.white;
    } else if (dataText == "2") {
      MyColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 180, 180, 180);
      MyColorText = Colors.white;
    } else {
      MyColor = Colors.white;
      MyColorText = Colors.black;
    }
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      height: uHeight,
      child: Card(
        color: MyColor,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            _dataText = (int.parse(dataText) + 1).toString();
            if (int.parse(dataText) > 2) dataText = "0";
            setState(() {                         // <<== setstate called here
              dataText = _dataText;
            });
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              dataText,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: MyColorText),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am i missing? Why can't i call setState to update the State and display the modification.

***Edit:***
Here is the error message with more details:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
setState() called in constructor: UserDisplay#b38b8(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not
mounted)
This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into
the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is
already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.

...

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#e418d
```

Comment: Should the ontap be on the card or text inside the card? Try wrapping  the card with inkwell and set state in the ontap

Comment: I'm getting the same error by wrapping the Card with InkWell.

Comment: I feel like I am not passing the context correctly. Would that make sens? What is the proper way to pass the BuildContext to a new class and new widget?

Comment: I'm abandoning this architecture. It's causing too many issues. Re-writting the code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

. Try this

```
  
class UserDisplay extends groupView {
  UserDisplay({Key? key,}) : super(groupParam: "groupParam", key: key);

  Widget DataCard(String dataText, double uHeight, context) {
    // dataText == null ? dataText = "" : dataText = dataText;
    Color MyColor = Colors.blue;
    Color MyColorText = Colors.white;
    var _dataText;

    if (dataText == "1") {
      MyColor = Colors.blue;
      MyColorText = Colors.white;
    } else if (dataText == "2") {
      MyColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 180, 180, 180);
      MyColorText = Colors.white;
    } else {
      MyColor = Colors.white;
      MyColorText = Colors.black;
    }
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      height: uHeight,
      child: Card(
        color: MyColor,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
if (int.parse(dataText) > 2) {
            
            setState(() {

            dataText = "0";
_dataText = (int.parse(dataText) + 1).toString();                         // <<== setstate called here
              dataText = _dataText;
            });
}
          },
          
          
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              dataText,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: MyColorText),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's my mistake when asking the question. Double checked, the setState is indeed in the onTap method. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: What's the logic behind the if statement?

Comment: the if logic is to have dataText moving in a loop on each tap: "0" > "1" >"2" > "0" . This way i get 3 different states for which i can implement different settings